# How do I get an nvarchar from MS SQL as string using ODBC (C++)?

Tags: c++, string, nvarchar, odbc

I'm trying to extract a string from my SQL database, but for some reason my parameters are wrong and I'm not sure why. Here is my code:

```
SQLHENV environHandle;
SQLHDBC connectHandle;
SQLHSTMT statement;
SQLCHAR* connectString = "MY_CONNECTION_STRING";
string path;
int jobID;  
SQLINTEGER pathstrlen = SQL_NTS;

SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &environHandle);
SQLSetEnvAttr(environHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, SQL_IS_INTEGER);
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, environHandle, &connectHandle);
SQLDriverConnect(connectHandle, NULL, connectString, SQL_NTS, NULL, 1024, NULL, SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT);
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, connectHandle, &statement);

//THIS IS THE BINDPARAMETER WITH THE ISSUE...
SQLBindParameter(statement, 1, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_CHAR, SQL_VARCHAR, 400, 0, (SQLPOINTER)path.c_str(), path.length(), &pathstrlen);

SQLBindParameter(statement, 2, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_INTEGER, SQL_INTEGER, 10, 0, &jobID, 0, &pathstrlen);

SQLExecDirect(statement, (SQLCHAR*)"{CALL SP(?,?)}", SQL_NTS);
```

It runs fine, but won't get the string information I requested, while the second parameter (to get an integer) works fine. I've tried changing the ParameterType to multiple different things but I either get errors thrown at me (SQL_LONGVARCHAR for example, is deprecated).

In SQL, the data I'm trying to get is as follows:

```
@Path nvarchar(4000) OUT
set @Path = 'test'
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who can shed light on this. I've been pulling my hair out all day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ODBC supports [Unicode parameter types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714651%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) so use `SQL_C_WCHAR` and `SQL_WVARCHAR` instead of `SQL_C_CHAR` and `SQL_VARCHAR` respectively.

You have two other issues as well.

First you are passing an ANSI `string` as a parameter.  If you are using Unicode you need to use a wide string - `wstring` instead.

Second you are not passing a valid buffer to `SQLBindParameter`.  The value returned by [string.c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) is a `const char*` that is a read only buffer.  It is not valid to pass hat to a function that requires a writable buffer - doing this will corrupt your string.  However you won't see any corruption in your case because you the call to `path.length()` WILL return zero so `SQLBindParameter` will never return any data.

You will need to declare `WCHAR` array buffer and pass that to `SQLBindParameter` which will give it a valid buffer to write data into.  You can then transfer that buffer to a `wstring` if you need it in a C++ object.

So something like this:

```
WCHAR path[401];  // 401 - width of you column + 1 for the null terminator
SQLBindParameter(statement, 1, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_WVARCHAR, 400, 0,     (SQLPOINTER)path, sizeof(path), &pathstrlen);
```

**Edit**

Ffrom looking at the [ODBC data conversion table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms716298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it appears that you should be able to get ODBC to convert that data from Unicode to ANSI for you if you to not want to deal with Unicode strings in your application.

```
char path[401];  // 401 - width of you column + 1 for the null terminator
SQLBindParameter(statement, 1, SQL_PARAM_OUTPUT, SQL_C_WCHAR, SQL_WVARCHAR, 400, 0,     (SQLPOINTER)path, sizeof(path), &pathstrlen);
```

Comment: thank you very much for that informative and accurate answer. It is incredibly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure you are right wrt "If you are using Unicode you need to use a wide string" and wrt your edit. Even if you've build your app with unicode defined for ODBC, you should be able to pass SQL_VARCHAR to SQLBindParameter and the driver should return you an ansi string. Also, passing SQL_WVARCHAR but providing a char path[401] will still put wide chrs in path and not ansi chrs.