# How to read Asian characters from SQL database in c++

Tags: c++, sql, sql-server, ascii

I am using C++ to read data from a SQL Server 2008 database. I can read normal ASCII characters just fine. However, I cant seem to figure out how to read Korean, Japanese, or Russian characters from the database. The following is the function that I am currently using to execute SQL commands to read strings from the database:

```
vector<string> ExSQL(string command) {
    SQLHANDLE sqlConnHandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlEnvHandle;
    SQLWCHAR retconstring[SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN];
    sqlConnHandle = NULL;
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvHandle);
    SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvHandle, &sqlConnHandle);
    SQLDriverConnect(sqlConnHandle,
        NULL,
        (SQLWCHAR*)L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost, 1433;DATABASE=PhraseDB3;Trusted=true;",
        SQL_NTS,
        retconstring,
        1024,
        NULL,
        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT
    );
    vector<string> results;
    SQLHANDLE sqlStmtHandle;
    sqlStmtHandle = NULL;
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlConnHandle, &sqlStmtHandle);
    wstring widestr = std::wstring(command.begin(), command.end());
    const wchar_t* temp = widestr.c_str();
    SQLExecDirect(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)temp, SQL_NTS);
    SQLCHAR sqlRes[SQL_RESULT_LEN];
    SQLINTEGER sqlResPtr;
    while (SQLFetch(sqlStmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
        SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, 1, SQL_CHAR, sqlRes, SQL_RESULT_LEN, &sqlResPtr);
        string result((const char*)sqlRes);
        results.push_back(result);
    }
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlStmtHandle);
    SQLDisconnect(sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlEnvHandle);
    return results;
}
```

This function works great for normal English strings, but does not work with Asian or Russian strings ("?" appears for each character). I tried to replace the strings in this function with wstring, but no luck. I also changed SQLExecDirect to SQLExecDirectW. Please help me change this function so that I can read all types of characters. Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14736123/7034621

Comment: Asian characters can be read with a Unicode character string. From what I see, if the string you are using is the default string in the language implementation, only the ASCII characters are represented correctly

Comment: While Saving the file, Choose Save With Encoding and Select UTF-8 format Option. May resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this function does what I was looking for:

```
vector<wstring> ExWSQL(string command) {
    SQLHANDLE sqlConnHandle;
    SQLHANDLE sqlEnvHandle;
    SQLWCHAR retconstring[SQL_RETURN_CODE_LEN];
    sqlConnHandle = NULL;
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &sqlEnvHandle);
    SQLSetEnvAttr(sqlEnvHandle, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, (SQLPOINTER)SQL_OV_ODBC3, 0);
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlEnvHandle, &sqlConnHandle);
    SQLDriverConnect(sqlConnHandle,
        NULL,
        (SQLWCHAR*)L"DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost, 1433;DATABASE=PhraseDB3;Trusted=true;",
        SQL_NTS,
        retconstring,
        1024,
        NULL,
        SQL_DRIVER_NOPROMPT
    );
    vector<wstring> results;
    SQLHANDLE sqlStmtHandle;
    sqlStmtHandle = NULL;
    SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlConnHandle, &sqlStmtHandle);
    wstring widestr = std::wstring(command.begin(), command.end());
    const wchar_t* temp = widestr.c_str();
    SQLExecDirectW(sqlStmtHandle, (SQLWCHAR*)temp, SQL_NTS);
    SQLWCHAR sqlRes[SQL_RESULT_LEN] = {};
    SQLINTEGER sqlResPtr;
    while (SQLFetch(sqlStmtHandle) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
        SQLGetData(sqlStmtHandle, 1, SQL_WCHAR, sqlRes, SQL_RESULT_LEN, &sqlResPtr);
        wstring result = (const WCHAR*)sqlRes;
        results.push_back(result);
    }
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, sqlStmtHandle);
    SQLDisconnect(sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, sqlConnHandle);
    SQLFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, sqlEnvHandle);
    return results;
}
```

It just uses wstrings and wchars instead of strings and chars.